# Preventing IP wildcard address from binding to entire loopback range

Tags: windows, ip, wildcard

Servers often use the IPv4 wildcard address 0.0.0.0 to bind to all interfaces, one of these being the loopback interface (127.0.0.0/8).

On Windows, is it possible to prevent binding to the entire loopback range and perhaps limit it to only the localhost address (127.0.0.1)?

Comment: It's 127.0.0.0/8

Comment: @Iain Thanks for pointing it out. I've corrected my question.

Comment: for what service?

Comment: @Jacod Evans. Not sure I understand your question. My question is about changing the system configuration to prevent a server daemon from binding to the entirety of the IP range in the loopback interface when the wildcard IP address is used.